# linux: iotop install not working

Tags: linux

I have tried to install `iotop` on linux with `sudo apt-get install iotop` and `sudo apt-get install iotop -y`. But when typing `iotop` in the console i receive error message: `command not found`. It seemed pretty straightforward to install (https://lintut.com/install-iotop-on-linux/) - and the install perform normally without returning error messages,  so it's hard to tell for me what I might have done wrong...

Any hint appreciated.

---

I found those related issues browsing the web some more:
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/anybody-knows-how-to-install-iotop-839411/

and especially this one:
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/194893 and this one: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=497360

my kernel version (when typing -uname) is 3.16.0-4-amd64 though.

Comment: tried it as root? you could try searching for it: `sudo which iotop`

Comment: Use `dpkg -L iotop` to see what was installed.  You should see `/usr/sbin/iotop`.  You probably do not have `/usr/sbin` in your path.

Comment: yep iotop requires root priviliges, but command not found :/ it's strange. Are u sure, that package really installed?

Comment: @William Pursell Yes I see both `usr/sbin` and `usr/sbin/iotop` when typing `dpkg -L iotop`. the command iotop still doesnt work though...

Comment: @jimbasquiat That is because /usr/sbin is not in your $PATH.

Comment: @jimbasquiat please clarify, did you try `sudo iotop`? That helped me address this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Running with `sudo` fixed this issue for me. The original poster posted that

> when I run /usr/sbin/iotop I receive the error message: Netlink error: Operation not permitted (1) The Linux kernel interfaces that iotop relies on now require root priviliges or the NET_ADMIN capability. This change occured because a security issue (CVE-2011-2494) was found that allows leakage of sensitive data across user boundaries. If you require the ability to run iotop as a non-root user, please configure sudo to allow you to run iotop as root. I was thus able to run the app using sudo /usr/sbin/iotop from the root user.

in a deleted comment - so the issues were with permissions, and running with sudo would sort that out.

Comment: Erm, guys? The comments in the other answer says that running as sudo worked. Its a valid answer, just needed some polish. Not sure that the comments here and the downvotes reflect.... well reality. I've worked in the information from the other speculative post, and that answer as a comment so we have a fuller picture of what's going on.